# How to represent predicates in RDF triples <s,p,o> by RDFlib

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib, knowledge-graph

I am able to generate my RDF triples in .ttl format. I would like to ask two things:

1. When I save my RDF triples in .ttl format. It is saved taking subjects in alphabetical order automatically(triples subjects follow alphabetical order in my .ttl file foreg: triple's subject starts with "a" comes first, then triple's subject starts with b and so on...) Could anyone tell, why it is so?
2. When I am trying to apply URIRef to handle rdf triples predicates(URIs) for which I am getting a warning message: 'Predicate'  does not look like a valid URI, trying to serialize this will break.
   What Should I change in my code (As of now I provided OWL.Ontology type for predicate) ?

my code snippet:

````
    """ Builds a rdf graph with the result triples """
    EX=Namespace("http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type")
    g = Graph()
    for triple in triples:
        g.bind('ex',EX)
        g.bind('foaf', FOAF)
        g.bind('schema', SDO)
        g.bind('dcterms',DCTERMS)
        subj = triple[0]
        pred = triple[1]
        objct =triple[2]
        g.add((subj, OWL.Ontology, objct))
   g.serialize(destination='file' + str(counter) + ".ttl", format='ttl'
    return g```


RDF triples: <s,p,o>
For the sentence: Serena Williams Beats Venus Williams to Win Her 7th Australian Open Title

For predicates getting this warning msg:
Beats to Win does not look like valid URI, trying to serialize this will break.

[[rdflib.term.URIRef('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Serena_Williams'),
rdflib.term.URIRef('Beats to Win'),
rdflib.term.URIRef('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Venus_Williams')],
[rdflib.term.URIRef('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Serena_Williams'),
rdflib.term.URIRef('Beats to Win'),
rdflib.term.URIRef('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Wikipedia')],
[rdflib.term.URIRef('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Serena_Williams'),
rdflib.term.URIRef('Beats to Win'),
rdflib.term.URIRef('http://dbpedia.org/resource/2013_Australian_Open')]]

generated rdf triples file in .ttl: (triples are arranged in alphabetical order automatically and predicates is belong to OWL ontology)

@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Serena_Williams> owl:Ontology <http://dbpedia.org/resource/2013_Australian_Open>,
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/2014_Australian_Open>,
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Draw_(chess)>,
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Injury>,
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Title>,
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States>,
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Venus_Williams>,
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Wikipedia> .
````

Comment: why are you using `OWL.Ontology` as the predicate of your triples? What's the point here? That doesn't make sense at all. `owl:Ontology` is an OWL vocabulary built-in class, this is never used as a predicate.

Comment: And your warning comes from `"Beats to Win"` - does this look like a URI for you? This is nothing more than a plain string. A URI has a  schema and an authority and ... see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986 or just the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier - and yes, predicates have to be URIs, you can't use string literals as predicates in RDF

Comment: Regarding your triples, how did you create them? Their semantics looks strange. `(<Serena Williams>,  <Beats to Win>, <Wikipedia>)` ???

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I am new to knowledge graphs using RDFlib. when I did not get any URI for relations or predicates then I was trying various namespace forms to convert the predicate into rdflib.term.URIref form. Could you please suggest something how should I represent predicates in rdf form?

Comment: For your "beats to win" predicate, define a proper URI for it and then assign to it the `rdfs:label "Beats to win"`. This is for convenience and self-documentation; any old URI in the predicate will give you valid RDF.

Comment: And regarding the triples, I have applied various preprocessing to find the subjects, predicate, objects, auxiliary verbs, clauses to finally segregate them to triples<s,p,o>. Most of the triples that are formed seem to be correct in the .ttl file. But some of the triples are also generated whose semantics looks strange as you said.

Comment: @alexis For my dataset, Likewise "Beats to triples" I have around 100000 triples generated in .ttl file . So how should I find ```rdfs:label``` for each and every predicate? Could you provide some example?

Comment: "to finally segregate them"? Your output shows a bunch of triples in abbreviated (TTL) form:  `<SerenaWilliams> owl:Ontology value1` , `<SerenaWilliams> owl:Ontology value2`, and so on. There is nothing wrong with this form, if that's what you meant. To see the individual triples (very verbose), use the "N-Triples" serialization.

Comment: "So how should I find rdfs:label for each and every predicate?" The label is to define the predicate itself. I am afraid you need to put your code aside and read a tutorial or introduction to RDF, because it is not possible to answer your questions like this.

Comment: @alexis Okay, Let me try what you suggested, and will get back here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The order of RDF predicates is not meaningful. If RDFlib chooses alphabetical order for the serialization, just roll with it. For actual query results (with SPARQL), you can add an ORDER BY term to control the order; but those are tabular data, not triples.

In RDF, the subject and predicate of triples should be a URI. To get off the ground you can use any URI at all and it's valid RDF, but then choose yourself a URI prefix (`https://i.am.learning` will do until you understand what's going on), define URIs in that space, and assign them labels with `rdfs:label` so that they have a human-readable name. Then you can use your predicate (just the URI part) in any number of triples.

Later you can use owl to define your predicates and other URIs as classes, predicates with a domain and range, etc.